# What is the easiest way to make an HTTP GET request with IOS 5?

Tags: ios, http, post, get

I am trying to send a suggestion from my app to a php file on my web server, I have tested the php script in my browser which sends an email to the user and stores the suggestion in my database, which all works fine.. And when running the following script I get a successful connection via IOS however i do not receive the results in my database..

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://blahblah.com/suggest.php?s=%@&n=%@&e=%@", suggestion, name, email];

    // Create the request.
    NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:post]
                                              cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                          timeoutInterval:60.0];

    // create the connection with the request
    // and start loading the data
    NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

    if (theConnection) {

        NSLog(@"Connection establisted successfully");

    } else {

        NSLog(@"Connection failed.");

    }
```

I have checked all the strings and encoded all spaces with %20 etc.. Can anyone see any glaringly obvious reason why my script won't work?

What is the easiest way to make a HTTP request from my app without opening safari?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You problem is that you're creating the connection, but are not sending the actual "connect" request.  Instead of

```
NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
```

try using this piece of code:

```
NSURLResponse* response = nil;
NSData* data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&response error:nil]
```

This is quick and dirty solution, but keep in mind that while this connection is in progress, your UI thread will appear to be frozen.  The way around it is to use asynchronous connection method, which is a bit more complicated than the above.  Search web for *NSURLConnection send asynchronous request* - the answer is there.